# legend tag overlaps with table fields

Tags: html, css

I am developing a website and I have trouble with legend field which is overlapping with the table fields. I had posted the code on http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/web-design/html-and-css/threads/351601.
I searched google for this kind of error but could not resolve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove `position: absolute;` from the following css selector

```
#registerForm legend {
    color: #999999;
    float: left;
    font-size: 1em;
    left: 1em;
    line-height: 1.3em;
    margin: 0;
    padding-top: 1.25em;
    position: absolute;
    width: 16%;
}
```

Demo at http://jsbin.com/ivoyi4

Answer (score 0):

After removing the position:absolute It looks better in the Firefox but in the safari the word is wrapped to the next line i.e., "User" in the first line and "information" in the second line above the table. What I wanted is to push the user information to the left side where the table starts but it acts weird in firefox with the position as absolute.